# How do I draw a line in CSS that starts wide and ends in a point

Tags: html, css, line, css-shapes

I hate drawing boring straight lines.
How would I draw a line that starts wide and ends narrow using html/css
[similar to the one shown in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k3Fz1.jpg).

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, that looks more like a compressed right-angle triangle (albeit tilted a bit). So you should be able to achieve that by creating a triangle (there are umpteen examples of that) and then rotating/skewing a bit.

Comment: You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of what Harry mentioned

```css
.triangle{
  border-top:10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom:10px solid transparent;
  border-right:300px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="triangle"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I got it